# Why is my Sieve of Eratosthenes running so slowly?

Tags: python, algorithm, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am writing a prime number program in Python for the Sieve of Eratosthenes. Although it seems to work, it's very slow.  How can I speed this up?

```
primes = []
upperLimit = 1000

for x in range(2,upperLimit):
  primes.append(x)
for y in range(0,int(len(primes)**0.5)):
  remove = []
  for j in range(primes[y]**2,upperLimit,primes[y]):
    remove.append(j)
  for i in remove:
    if i in primes:
      primes.remove(i)

print(primes)
```

Update:
Thanks to the help from the answers, I rewrote the code using boolean values rather than numbers. A list below 100000 now runs in less than 6 seconds.

```
i = 2
limit = 100000
primes = [True] * limit
primes[0] = False
while i < limit**0.5:
    if primes[i-1]:
        for x in range(i * 2, limit + 1,i):
            primes[x-1] = False
    i += 1
count = 1
total = []
for i in primes:
    if i:
        total.append(count)
    count += 1
print(total)
```

Comment: How slow is slow, and what system/Python are you using? You also should ask yourself if you are creating too many lists and thus creating a large amount of memory that doesn't need to be created.

Comment: The culprit is `primes.remove`, which is an O(N) operation

Comment: It took about 30 seconds to run with a limit of 20000, when I tried values upwards of 1000000, I just stopped after about 10 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the main inefficiency in your code is the `list` of primes you're maintaining. Although it may not be obvious, calling `primes.remove` is a very expensive operation. It needs to walk through the `list` to try to find the value you're removing, and then it needs to modify the `list` by moving all the elements after the one you're looking for.

E.g.

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
l.remove(5)  # This has to look at all the elements in l, since 6 isn't there
l.remove(0)  # This finds 1 quickly but then has to move every element to the left
```

A more traditional approach to the Sieve of Eratosthenes is to use an array (`list` in Python) of all the numbers you're considering, where each element is a boolean indicating whether the number could be prime.

Mimicking the above example:

```
l = [True, True, True, True, True]
l[0] = False  # Just goes straight to that element and changes its value
```

Here's an example of how to write that code:

```
primes = [True] * 100000

# We already know 2 is the first prime
primes[0] = False
primes[1] = False

# Fine to stop at sqrt(len(primes)) here as you're already doing    
for i in range(2, len(primes)):
    if primes[i]:
        for j in range(i**2, len(primes), i):
            primes[j] = False

print([n for n, is_prime in enumerate(primes) if is_prime])
```

You'll find this is much faster because indexing into a `list` and changing a value that way is quite efficient.

Comment: what does the if statement do? Also, what does the last line of code (the print function) do?

Comment: The `if` statement just skips numbers that have already been proven to not be prime. The print statement is sort of like `for i in range(len(primes)): if primes[i]: print(i)`. It prints out the numbers that are still marked as `True` (possibly primes) in the `list`.

Answer (score 0):

It's slow because there are a lot of operations you're doing far more often than needed.  the life span of a composite number **N** looks something like this:

- append **N** to **primes**
- for each *small* number **I** ( < sqrt(limit) )

  - Append all *large* multiples of **I** to **remove**
- for each **I** in **remove**

  - if **I** is still in **primes**, delete it.

That's a lot of "touches" for each number.  That's also a lot of *small* numbers to consider.

Instead, try this:

- Make a list of Booleans (all **True**), one for each potential prime.
- While the lowest value **I** marked **True** < sqrt(limit):

  - Clear (turn **False**) all large multiples of **I**
  - Note: don't bother to check whether the value is already **False**

At this point, your primes are exactly those values still marked **True**